# Running jquery on webform submit

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I've created a jquery function to score a webform based on user input and display the scores in disabled number fields on the webform when the user clicks a Score button. I would also like the function to run again when the user clicks submit, in order to capture any changes made to responses after the user clicked the score button. I've tried a couple of different ways of referring to the submit button, none are working. Is there a way of running jquery between clicking Submit and actually submitting the form?

```
function caclulateScore() {
// does awesome stuff
};
$("#score").click(calculateScore);
//This works as intended.

$("#submit").click(calculateScore);
$("#submit").submit(calculateScore);
$("input[name=op]").click(calculateScore);
//These do not.
```

Comment: use jquery submit  like: .closest("form").submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It will call `calculateScore()` before actually submitting the form.

```
$("#submit").submit(function(){
    calculateScore();
});
```

Comment: That didn't work either. :( It just submits the form without running the function.

Comment: See if [this](https://hastebin.com/divolomexi.js) works. preventDefault(); will halt form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I think part of the problem is that it may be the wrong element reference. I added an alert before my function and it did not fire. Here is the div that contains the button. It doesn't have an element ID like everything else. `<div class="form-actions"><input class="webform-submit button-primary form-submit" type="submit" name="op" value="Submit"></div>`

Comment: `$("#submit")` won't work if the element doesn't have `id="submit"`. Try [this](https://hastebin.com/ziteyihota.scala)

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help! I wasn't able to assign an element ID because it is supplied by the webform module. I just used the class selector and added a line to submit the form after. Seems to work exactly as I wanted. 
`$(".form-submit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      calculateScore();
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

use [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) submit:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to coding. Do I use those IDs or form-specific IDs?